# Appropriate encryption for financial data

Tags: php, mysql, security, encryption

I'm currently building a web application(PHP/MySQL) which saves data from persons. Most of this data is not worth protecting with encryption but some of it is financial information like income and so on. It is not a payment application and does not store information that could be turned into money directly like credit card information but still stuff you don't want to have in a possible leak. This platform has to be sold to customers that want "security", but that can mean anything as the customers themselves do not have any knowledge what they really want, since they are business people and not cryptographers(like me neither).

It is a management platform so the people that have their financial data saved there are not the users of the platform. Users of the platform are merely a login with permissions attached to them. The server itself never has to have access the data. Every operation is done by a user(could also be an admin) that is logged in. Multiple users need to have access to the same data given they have enough permissions.

My question is now how I can protect the financial data from these threats:

- Somebody finds an SQL-injection and dumps all tables remotely
- Somebody steals the hard drive of the server (database + code)

Where I'm certainly not going: Large scale sniffing attack or compromised servers(like sniffing all traffic on the server itself where SSL doesn't matter) or social engineering/phishing.

I would also like to have a quick summary how much more information(keys, data, etc.) I have to store in comparison to the current system, where there is one simple field for income etc. and a standard login system with username and hashed password.

EDIT: Reformulated question almost entirely following the suggestion of comments/answers

Comment: I'd think you'd do something with a key generated in a reproducible manner using the user's password (but is not the password itself or the password hash you keep in the database), then you'd demand the password be inputted every time the user needs access to the sensitive data. That way you don't keep the encryption key in code. Whether its symmetric or asymmetric doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: @apokryfos I did edit my question and probably clarified some things. Your comment was already pretty close I think so I would like to have your answer too so I can upvote it :)

Comment: *"I'm currently building a web application... This platform has to be sold to customers..."* - Your company should probably enlist the services of a security architect. Either hire one or consult with one. One of the things you want to avoid is presenting it to a company, and one of the company's security architects reviews and rejects it. (I used to be one of the security architects that reviewed vendor products. They are called "Security Architecture Evaluations").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, the following key points stand out.

- The server itself never has to have access to the data.
- Multiple users need to have access to the same data given they have enough permissions.
- Maintain security even if:

  - Somebody finds an SQL-injection and dumps all tables remotely.
  - Somebody steals the hard drive of the server (database + code).

---

This is possible to achieve, but not trivial.  The thing that makes this possible is the fact that the server does not require access to the data.  This allows us to use user passwords to derive keys.

Each level in your permission structure will have an associated key.  This key will be used to encrypt data that can be viewed with those permissions.  When the first administrative account is created, generate a key for each level in your permission structure and use the administrative password as an input for a KDF and derive a key.  Use this password-derived key to encrypt each permission key and store the resulting ciphertexts alongside the administrative account.

As new users are created and assigned ranks by the administrative account, pull the highest level permission key that the new user will have access to, as well as any keys at a lower permission, decrypt them with the administrative password (which will be required for creating users) and then encrypt them again with the new users password and store alongside the new user in the database.

This system allows you to pass the required encryption keys to each user and makes accessing data above the users permission level cryptographically impossible.

At this point, it is rather straight forward for you to allow users to access data by simply taking their password, decrypting the relevant permission key and then using that key to decrypt the data.  Users changing their password is also trivial as it simply means you have to decrypt the permission keys with the old password then re-encrypt with the new password.

---

At a more technical level, I would recommend the following:

- Use AES.  AES-256 tends to be the most common but AES-128 is just as secure in the grand scheme of things.  Use of an authenticated block mode (GCM) isn't as important here but is still recommended.   If not, use a mode like CBC or CTR with an HMAC.
- Never use a password directly as a key.  Use PBKDF2 to generate keys from passwords.  Using AES-256 fits in nicely here because you can use SHA-256 as the primitive to PBKDF2 and get output the same length as the internal hash function.
- Generate a new random IV every time you encrypt using a CSPRNG.  Prefix the IV to the ciphertext.  Don't derive an IV from PBKDF2 like the key.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. So there will be #userswithpermission versions of the permission key just encrypted with different passwords(the KDFd version of it ofc)? And I do need to save the IV to be able to decrypt the ciphertext again, right? Just like salted hashes?

Comment: Yes that is correct.  And yes you need to store the IV.  Prepend the IV to your ciphertext each time you encrypt and then simply remove it and use it when decrypting.  The only similarity it has to a salt is that it's a required piece of information to complete the operation.  They share nothing else in common :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are two approaches to this:

1) Use symmetric encryption because you have already arranged a secret with the client, which is their password.

Whenever the user requires access to their sensitive information, they need to provide their password. If you require this, then you can use that password as a basis of generating the encryption key.

You can use the [`openssl`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php) functions in PHP to encrypt the sensitive data, and decrypt it when the client needs it. This will allow you to select an appropriately hard to break algorithm which OpenSSL supports. The drawback of this is that you will need explicit user permission and their password to access that data, which is good if you're only storing it on behalf of that user, but bad if you need to pass it on to someone else.

This way you will not need to store additional information in the database. In case someone steals your hard drive, all they will have is encrypted sensitive data and hashed passwords. The drawback is that it's a single point of failure, if they break the encryption they also get the password and vice-versa however the difficulty of breaking the encryption is not as high as reversing a hash. It also relies on strong passwords, which as we know users often don't tend to use, however that's not a new problem and one we're not likely to solve today.

2) Require the user to generate a private-public key pair and send you the public key. You can then store this public key and encrypt data using it. This generally would work well if you had an app/software that communicates with your server, which can do this on the user's behalf, but is harder to implement in a web application. Perhaps there's JavaScript libraries that can do this but since it's not something that is commonly done you need to be 100% sure the library you're using is secure. However this also requires of the user to store the key somewhere and be able to use it whenever they want access to that data (again JavaScript can do this for the user but saving and loading the key is something that requires user interaction due to security concerns).

In short:

1. Symmetric encryption would only be secure if the encryption key is not stored on the server but is something that the user can provide whenever it is needed.
2. Asymmetric encryption is even more secure but unrealistic in a web application targeted to an average user.

So I would suggest symmetric encryption using the user's password as a key.

Comment: Do I need to store multiple encrypted copies of the data if I want multiple users to access that same data? Or at least multiple encrypted copies(with the user pw) of the encryption key for the data? And is it ok to store the encrypted data in the memory for the time of the session?

Comment: @SkryptX For the first part, if you want others to view sensitive data, this whole approach breaks down. In that case you can use assymetric encryption with a specific private key stored somewhere securely (on a different server) with the ability to use an authorised and authenticated user's credentials to retrieve that key. For the second part, having the sensitive data in memory at some point is inevitable. All you can do is dispose of it properly when you don't need it anymore and be mindful of buffer overflow/underflow attacks.

Comment: Is it that bad to have like 20-30 copies of the decryption key encrypted with different passwords? If the passwords are secure and that would only reduce the strength by 20-30 times which still would require an insane amount of computing or am I just naive? :S

Comment: @SkryptX I have added another answer after you significantly changed your question.  Allowing users to view the same information is possible while maintaining security.  While the author of this answer is correct that asymmetric crypto could be used here, it is definitely not an elegant solution.  A cleaner system can be achieved with just symmetric encryption, as I explain in my second answer.

Comment: Additionally, @apokryfos, can you please cite your reference for "the difficulty of breaking the encryption is not as high as reversing a hash"?

Comment: @LukePark well, reversing a hash is impossible (because the original data is not really stored anywhere) while breaking encryption is not. To "reverse" a hash you have to find a collision.

Comment: I understood that statement to mean "breaking an encryption algorithm is easier than breaking a hashing algorithm".  Is that what you meant?

Comment: @LukePark I would say it is. The algorithms themselves are not easier or harder to break, but the encrypted data itself gives you hints on what it is, a password hash is generally of constant length but an encrypted string length is generally proportional to the unencrypted length, meaning you know more about encrypted data than you do about hashed data right off the bat.

Comment: While you are correct that encrypted data gives indication to the length of the plaintext, it does not make **finding** that plaintext any easier than finding what data produced a hash.  I think the statement in your answer is misleading, truthfully.

Comment: @LukePark The more you know about the data the more effective an attack you can perform. You can pick the most easy targets over the harder ones (e.g. it's easier to break shorter strings than longer ones). If you only have a single encrypted string and a single hash it makes no difference, but at scale it does.

Comment: Encrypted data is indistinguishable from random noise. There are no "easy ones" and "hard ones". You speak about modern encryption as if it's something that you spend a day or so breaking. This isn't the case. I also disagree that breaking "shorter strings" is easier. With modern encryption the length is irrelevant. [In classical crypto](http://crypto.interactive-maths.com/kasiski-analysis-breaking-the-code.html), sometimes longer ciphertexts are easier to break.

Answer (score 0):

Asymmetric encryption and hybrid encryption are pointless here unless the users generate and retain ownership of the private keys themselves.  I infer from the rest of your question that this isn't the case.

Assuming you want to be able to view this encrypted information without user interaction (e.g. you aren't just storing this information for the user and the information is relevant to your business operations), you have limited storage options.

If your exact threat model is to protect this data in the event of a database leak **and nothing else**, symmetric encryption is perfect, if properly implemented.

The implication of this is that the symmetric key must be stored on servers that make requests to the database and serve the data to your other (likely front-end) systems.  If any of those servers were to become compromised, then the encrypted data will be leaked.

In summary, use symmetric encryption, but understand that it will only protect you directly from a database leak through something like SQL injection or a similar attack.  A compromised server is a compromised server and generally means full data access given enough time.

EDIT: If you intend to require user interaction to view the secured data, then apokryfos's comment above accurately details what to do to secure the information.  Generate a symmetric key from the users password and use this to encrypt an additional symmetric key.  Use this secondary symmetric key to actually encrypt the data.  Using two keys makes a user password change easier.

Comment: The idea behind asymmetric encryption was that multiple people can have access to the same data while all the data is encrypted. So when sensitive data gets accessed it is always a user that does it with the respective permissions. So if somebody copies everything(db+code) they still need to find a password. But your comment on a compromised server is obviously true which makes that kinda useless.

Comment: @SkryptX Hmmmm I think there may be some aspect of asymmetric encryption that you are misunderstanding?  Might be a good idea to edit your question to clarify whether you need access to the data without user interaction also.

Comment: I did edit my question pretty much entirely. Maybe this explains my question better. I also did misunderstand asymmetric encryption in what it can do and what it can't do.